# ObjC: NSDictionary allKeysForObject *containing* (is this possible?)

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am very new to objective-C and came across the NSDictionary method  `allKeysForObject:`.  Seems very useful.  However, I have a NSDictionary which has several NSArrays (all of length 2) and which are keyed by NSStrings.  Basically, the keys are items and the arrays define their two properties.  If I wanted to pull all the item names that have a certain property, could this be done with something like `allKeysForObject`, or should I just loop over the dictionary and grow a mutable array (seems inefficient).

I'd include a code snippet, but I feel like this question is conceptual enough that code wouldn't really clarify anything.  Oh, what the hell.  Here's some simplified code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],nil],@"Car",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],nil],@"Boat",nil];
NSLog(@"%@",[dict allKeysForObject:???]); // this is the line I am not at all sure about.
```

EDIT: Thank you for the responses so far.  I was not clear about my question, though.  I am looking for a way to do something more general.  I don't want to retrieve all keys for a particular object, say `[1,2]`, but I want to look in the dictionary for all arrays including the NSNumber 1 and return those keys.  So if I added `@"Plane",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],nil]`, I'd like to somehow query for the NSNumber 1 and get `@"Car"` and `@"Plane"`.  I am getting the sense that this is not what this method was designed to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `-keysOfEntriesPassingTest:`...

```
NSArray * selectedKeys = [dict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
                          {
                              return [obj containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
                          }];
```

Comment: Aha! This looks right! Thank you, I'll need to play with it but thanks for pointing me on the right track!

Answer (score -2):

In your example, if you call

```
[dict allKeysForObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                            nil]]]
```

you should get an array containing just @"Boat"

Comment: Thank you, I see how that would work. Would it also be possible to match on just one of the elements? Basically, I want to match on a class of objects that contain the NSNumber 2, for example.  Ideally, this matching would be position independent, so it would match NSNumber 2 anywhere in the array.

Comment: No. allKeysForObject is supposed to return all the keys that map to the same object (in the sense of isEqual, not in the sense of having the same address). If you want to do what you say, you need to store something different than an NSArray. Create your own class and define isEqual as you want. Alternatively use keysOfEntriesPassingTest: or keysOfEntriesWithOptions:passingTest:

Comment: Ok, thank you, that makes sense.  I am trying to understand `keysOfEnteriesPassingTest` but that means understanding blocks, and that is just another level of complexity.  I am interested in what you said about redefining isEqual. Are you saying that if I stored the properties not as arrays, but instead created an "item" class, I could fill the dictionary with item objects that contained the arrays I currently have and use isEqual to do the comparison I want to do? What I want isn't really an "equality" situation, though, as you say. I just want to pull item names with a certain property.

Comment: allKeysForObject assumes you are interested in an equality situation. Of course if you define a class, what it means that two instances of it are equal is totally up to you: just implement isEqual accordingly. I do understand that blocks are something else to learn. But that's the current best practice to do what I think you want to do.